# Software to index files on a network

Tags: file-management

I have a few hard drives which are connected to a Linux machine or a OS X machine. Not all hard drives can be connected at the same time. I have access via ssh to all machines from each other.

I would like to be able to find whether there is a file that matches approximately or exactly a filename, whether the hard drive is currently mounted or not. I would also like to have the database to update automatically when the drive is mounted, knowing that it can be mounted on all machines.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution might be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but still:

When connecting the machines to a Linux machine, you could mount the drives to specific mount-points in your directory structure. If you do that via a script, you could include a call to the `updatedb` script of **[Locate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix))** – a software that ships with most Linux distributions. Additionally make sure that `updatedb` script (usually linked from `/etc/cron.daily`) does not run when those drives are *not* connected (to avoid having their content purged).

Then, from the Linux command line, you could simply use `locate myfilename` to locate every file including "myfilename" in its name – which would apply e.g. to `myfilename.txt`, `also_myfilename.jpg`, `myfilename_too.mp4`, etc. On which machine/drive the file is located, then becomes obvious by the path returned, e.g. `/mnt/machine1/drive_a/home/myuser/myfilename.txt` – provided you organized your mount points accordingly.

- cost: free
- installation: if not pre-installed already, simply use your package manager
- matches full or partly filename
- does however not match wildcards IMHO, and for sure not "soundex" (sounds the same/closely similar, but is spelled differently)